# How to change keymap on native console?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-layout, keymap, tty

When I'm switching to native console with Ctrl+Alt+Fn I have wrong keyboard maping. I want to set keymap proper to my language. In KDE, web browser, konsole etc. everything is OK.

So, how to change keymap on native console? How to figure out which keymap is currently loaded? Maybe it is font issue?

Answer (score 1):

Install the package which contains `loadkeys` and the keymaps data, i.e. in a Debian system:

```
apt install console-data kbd
```

then you can change the keymap, for example:

```
loadkeys de
loadkeys it
loadkeys us
```

and so on.